# Postgresql starup script for second instance?

Tags: ubuntu, script, postgresql, init

I need to run my second postgresql instance when linux boots. I added this command (like in postgresql documentation) in rc.local:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl start -l logfile -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main2
```

But if I try to run pg_ctl:

```
cannot be run as root

Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
t, it gives me this error:
```

How can I specify to run that command as postgres, but actually execute it with root (because root owns it).

Or is there some better way to make second init script for postgresql?

P.S. (I'm using Ubuntu)

Comment: Copied and pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/24078385/398670 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu, which it seems like you are, you don't have to roll any of this yourself.

Read the docs for `pg_ctlcluster`, `pg_createcluster`, `pg_lsclusters`. These are part of the `pg_wrapper` package for Ubuntu, which provides management of multiple instances and versions built-in.